# ImageButton fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Guys I am just a student, creating a movieapp as a project and I need some help, iI've been looking online and followed all the step and yet I am not able to click the imagebutton in the fragment. Please help me and teach me what's wrong.
im currently just doing imgdp which you can see the id of imgdp and the page i want to direct to is Deadpool2.class.

This is my fragment code:

```
public class fragment4 extends Fragment {

ImageButton imgbutton;
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public fragment4() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static fragment4 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragment4 fragment = new fragment4();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment4, container, false);
    imgbutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgdp);

               imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Deadpool2.class));
                    }
                });
        return view;
    }



public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragment4">

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Action"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.063"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgdp"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/deadpool"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/avengersinfinitywar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/avengersinfinitywar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/thor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/jurassic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.522" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/thor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/incredibles"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.063" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/kingsman"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/deadpool"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Adventure"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.065"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.347" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Comdey"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.065"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.691" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is My Home activity

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private Toolbar mToolbar;

private Home.SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new Home.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
                break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment3, container, false);
            break;
            case 4:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment4, container, false);
            break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 4:
                return "SECTION 4";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you get? Try to make your question clearer to get proper help.

Comment: i didn't get any error , i can run the app, i using tabbed activity , when i in tab 4 which the image button is , i clicked and it didnt open up the class

Comment: im using 4 different fragment because i have total of 4 tab

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate any possible error and maybe you haven't added enough information about your challenge. Since you're learning I'm inclined to help and guide you. Feel free to contact anytime.

Comment: Or is it i changed framelayout to contraintlayout causes the problem

Comment: How do i contact you , this my first time using this

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Deadpool2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);